# How much information should I give my former boss when I lost a company key?

Tags: management, termination, security

I just ended my job and my last day was yesterday. I had lost my keys (I know, I'm bad) and informed the secretary who is encharge of them and she gave me a replacement set. The other day when I left my boss took my badges, keys etc. Today I received an e-mail from him (on my personal account) asking if I could look for them again and if I know where they may be.

I moved houses and went through everything
I phoned the bus company lost and found
I phoned the lost and found of the general area I live in

I always kept my keys in a certain pocket of my bag and I only took the bag to and from work. So should I tell him any of this in my e-mail or is it irrelevant?

I almost think they somehow fell out of the bag at work, or were stolen.

Comment: I think you know better. We can't know what relationships you have with your boss or what he expects from you.

Comment: Put it in writing that you have looked for and can't find them. That you believe it's possible they could have been lost or stolen. Did you warn them as soon as it happened? Mention that too. At this point you just want to protect yourself against possible blame for a break-in.

Comment: What paperwork was signed when you got them the first time? What paperwork was filled out when you got the replacement? I wouldn't put anything in writing yet.

Answer (score 4):

A lost key is always a potential breach of security. Your boss likely tries to measure the possible security impact of you losing your keys.

In the best case, it fell into some ditch, is picked up by a street cleaner who has no idea in which lock it fits, and it goes to the garbage. In that case there would be no reason to act.

In the worst case, it was selectively stolen by a criminal to break into your company and steal valuables or business secrets. That would mean that all locks and keys would need to be replaced immediately.

Your company might be insured against theft, but the insurance company would likely withhold payment unless your boss can prove that he acted (within reason) when he got the news that a key went missing. Asking you to search for it is the least he is expected to do.